# Is it possible to fly with liquids bought in a different airport?

Tags: airport-security, hand-luggage

I'm flying from Porto (OPO) to London Stansted (STN) and then from STN to Warsaw Modlin (WMI), about two hours afterwards. Both flights are with Ryanair. I wanted to buy some Port wine at the duty free zone in OPO, to take as a gift, hoping it would be cheaper than paying for two checked bags. However, I'm not even sure if this is possible. Will I need to go through security again in STN? If so, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that this is specific to European airports as listed in the question. It is not applicable worldwide as pointed out by @jpatokal.

**Yes**, according to this European [directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1460883999062&uri=CELEX:32015R1998):

> 4.1.3   Screening of liquids, aerosols and gels (LAGs)
>
> 4.1.3.1   LAGs carried by passengers may be exempted from screening with LEDS equipment upon entry to the SRA in the following cases:
>
> (a) 
>   if the LAG is in individual containers with a capacity not greater
>   than 100 millilitres or equivalent in one transparent resealable
>   plastic bag of a capacity not exceeding 1 litre, whereby the contents
>   of the plastic bag fit comfortably and the bag is completely closed;
>
> (b)
>   if the LAG is sealed in a dedicated STEB upon purchase locally at the
>   airport airside;
>
> (c)
>   **if the LAG in a STEB originates from another EU airport or an aircraft
>   of an EU carrier and is resealed in a dedicated STEB before leaving
>   the security restricted area of the airport**;
>
> (d)
>   if the LAG is screened locally with LEDS equipment airside and is then
>   sealed in a dedicated STEB.

LAG: Liquids Aerosols and Gels
STEB: Secure Tamper-Evident Bag

Ensure that the duty free item is sealed in a STEB at OPO with the receipt visible inside the bag.

Comment: This answer is true in Europe, so +1, but it's not universally true.  For example, flights to Australia will not accept STEBs on board.